# Spree shopping cart being replaced instead of merged upon user sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, spree, spree-auth-devise

Using Spree 3.0.8

When I perform the sequence:

1. add items to the shopping cart as a guest user (not signed in);
2. proceed to checkout (which prompts for a sign in);
3. sign in

My shopping cart is essentially replaced by the most recent incomplete order from the user that signed in.

I would expect that both guest and incomplete order be merged. 
At least it seems to be the intention in `spree_auth_devise`'s code.

Does anybody have a clue on why this might be happening?

Cheers,
Vasco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this was introduced in this commit:
https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise/commit/336b0e4f3a9c38dba36c8deef37549f48f61672f

While the above commit solves https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/6578,
it also discards the guest user's shopping cart since there is no email associated.

I reverted to the old code and the problem is solved (at the expense of introducing issue #6578 which, in my case, is not applicable).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an outdated version of Spree and don't want to update it, you can do a workaround to solve this problem.

What I've done is send the `guest_token` attribute from `Order` through the sign in submit and save it inside a session variable. After that, you should be able to find the `Order` after the sign in is completed.

Hope this helps!